# Text formatting, with nested dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, text, nested

I want to make a JSON tree from a CSV with a id+parent hierarchy. It works but I want the output slightly different.
Instead of returning just:

```
'childs': { ........... }
```

I would like it to return:

```
'childs': { placeholder: 'Select', items: { ........... } }
```

Or just:

```
'childs': { items: { ........... } }
```

Here's the code I am using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    import csv
    import re
    from collections import defaultdict
    from pprint import pprint

    parents = defaultdict(list)

    with open('data.csv',encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        next(reader)
        count = 1
        for row in reader:
            id_, name, admin_level, parent = row
            parents[parent].append((id_, name))
            count += 1

    def build_tree(d, val):
        return {'lc' + id_: {'val': 'lc' + id_, 'txt': name, 'childs': build_tree(d, id_)} for id_, name in d[val]}
    #pprint(build_tree(parents, ''))
    final = str(build_tree(parents, ''))
    print(final.replace(", 'childs': {}", ""))
```

The data.csv I'm using is:

```
@id,name,admin_level,parent_id
295480,Portugal,2,
2897141,Lisboa,3,295480
3920249,Aveiro,3,295480
5011694,Leiria,3,295480
5400843,Loures,4,2897141
5400844,Mafra,4,2897141
```

The present output is:

```
{'lc295480': {'childs': {'lc2897141': {'childs': {'lc5400843': {'childs': {},
                                                                'txt': 'Loures',
                                                                'val': 'lc5400843'},
                                                  'lc5400844': {'childs': {},
                                                                'txt': 'Mafra',
                                                                'val': 'lc5400844'}},
                                       'txt': 'Lisboa',
                                       'val': 'lc2897141'},
                         'lc3920249': {'childs': {},
                                       'txt': 'Aveiro',
                                       'val': 'lc3920249'},
                         'lc5011694': {'childs': {},
                                       'txt': 'Leiria',
                                       'val': 'lc5011694'}},
              'txt': 'Portugal',
              'val': 'lc295480'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `'childs': build_tree(d, id_)`
With `'childs' : { 'placeholder': 'Select', 'items' : build_tree(d, id_) }`
Or with `'childs' : { 'items' : build_tree(d, id_) }`

Also your replace to get rid of the empty childs keys `print(final.replace(", 'childs': {}", ""))` is bad. It would be better if

```
{'val': 'lc' + id_, 'txt': name, 'childs': build_tree(d, id_)}
```

Was built like this:

```
obj = {'val': 'lc' + id_, 'txt': name}
childs = build_tree(d, id_)
if childs:
   obj['childs'] = childs
```

`build_tree` would then look like this:

```
def build_tree(d, val):
    d = {}
    for id_, name in d[val]:
        obj = {'val': 'lc' + id_, 'txt': name}
        childs = build_tree(d, id_)
        if childs:
           obj['childs'] = childs
        d['lc' + id_] = obj
    return d
```